# ElasticSearch ends with query

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, elk

I am searching for data in kibana which ends with ":1"

I have a dataset like so for an my_field:

```
skdjjsdk:jkdsjkd:123:1:1
skdjjsdk:jkdsjkd:123:2:12
skdjjsdk:jkdsjkd:123:1:33
skdjjsdk:jkdsjkd:123:1:01
skdjjsdk:jkdsjkd:123:2:2
```

I tried searching in kibana search

```
my_field: "*:1"
my_field: ":1$"
```

also tried Elasticsearch Query DSL (in filter fields)

```
{
  "query": {
    "regexp": {
      "my_field": {
        "value": ".*:1"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But I am getting matched with

```
skdjjsdk:jkdsjkd:123:1:1
skdjjsdk:jkdsjkd:123:1:33
```

But I want only `skdjjsdk:jkdsjkd:123:1:1`

Answer (score 0):

I get the result using analyzer whitespace and wildcard query.

```
PUT idx_test
{
 "mappings": {
   "properties": {
     "my_field" :{
       "type": "text",
       "analyzer": "whitespace"
     }
   }
 }
}


POST idx_test/_doc/
{"my_field":"skdjjsdk:jkdsjkd:123:1:1"}

POST idx_test/_doc/
{"my_field":"skdjjsdk:jkdsjkd:123:2:12"}

POST idx_test/_doc/
{"my_field":"skdjjsdk:jkdsjkd:123:1:33"}

POST idx_test/_doc/
{"my_field":"skdjjsdk:jkdsjkd:123:1:01"}

POST idx_test/_doc/
{"my_field":"skdjjsdk:jkdsjkd:123:2:2"}


GET idx_test/_search
{
  "query": {
   "wildcard": {
     "my_field": {
       "value": "*:1"
     }
   }
  }
}
```

Comment: I am not getting any result for this as well

Comment: do you executed exactly the snippet code? This code works.